# Database Error at BackEnd no Exception message supplied

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, backend, djongo

I am creating a website using Django as BackEnd and MongoDB as my DataBase but I am experiencing an error while trying to add data into my Patient model using the admin dashboard, 1st entry doesn't trigger any exception however when I try to add 2nd patient my app crashes, and here are the screenshots of my model and my traceback

[My Patient Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNs2f.png) This model is inherited from the base model and also holds a self reference.

The TraceBack can be found here: https://dpaste.com/GB2REDLGA

However I tried to change my database and upon shifting to SQLite the error was gone. I don't know what is causing this error. Little help would be awesome.

Comment: I reproduced your code, and it worked without errors, here is the code https://github.com/cuevasDev/patient. I hope that helps